# Is it possible to configure debezium/kafka to recieve messages from multiple tables in a single topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, debezium

We are reliant on a single external database over which we have no control. For our purposes, we maintain a daily copy of that database that is used in our product and which we can configure and expand to our needs.

We're currently in the process of trying out Debezium and Kafka as a way of getting real-time updates. However, our use of one of the largest and most frequently updated tables in the source database is conditional upon a joined table. That join, due to the size of the data, is inefficient.

Ideally, we'd like to combine the data from both those source tables into a single table for our production use. We can try to do that at our end of the process using a mapper of some sort, but that will then be taking messages from two related topics and there are going to be problems with the efficiency of the upsert and the order in which the data is inserted.

It would be much better if we could configure it in Debezium or Kafka so that both tables fed into the same topic, which could then be fed through a single mapper into a single source table. From what I've read so far in the documentation, I suspect this isn't possible. But it would be useful if someone could clarify that and/or explain how to go about it if it is possible?

Comment: What issue are you having with setting up multiple connectors with the same output topic? Kafka doesn't care, and Debezium doesn't prevent it... Why wouldn't it be possible? Note : If tables have different schemas, you're going to need to use some logic in your consumer to split things apart, and that would be less ideal / scalable than consuming more than one topic and joining the data

Comment: @OneCricketeer it's purely inexperience. We've inherited this setup from a third party and are trying to figure out how to work with it and improve the configuration

Comment: Have you read into Kafka Streams joins or ksqlDB?